# Linq where clause with if condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following model:

```
class Project{
   bool IsDeleted {set;get;}
   ICollection<Document> Documents {set;get;}
}

class Document{
   Project Project {set;get;}
   int? ProjectId {set;get;}
}
```

I am querying Document repository, I want to get all the documents and also the documents whose project is not deleted.

```
        var documents = _repository.Include(p=>p.Project)
                                    .Where(m => m.IsDeleted == false)
                                    .Where(x=> x.Project.IsDeleted == false)
```

However , this is not working, because some documents are associated with projects where some arent. Ie: The documents that project is null, should return but this case dont.

What s the correct way to do this?

Comment: Is `IsDeleted` a `boolean`?

Comment: Do you want the documents that have a null project as well or not?

Comment: @MattBurland yes projects can be null. ie: independent documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

`.Where(m => !m.IsDeleted && (m.Project == null || !m.Project.IsDeleted))`

You need to check if `Project` is null before checking if `Project.IsDeleted`. If you don't want the ones where project isn't `null`, then you just need:

`.Where(m => !m.IsDeleted && m.Project != null && !m.Project.IsDeleted)`

Remember: Shortcut evaluation is your friend. In the first example, if `m.Project == null` then the it will evaluate to `true` and it won't even attempt to check `m.Project.IsDeleted` and you won't get the `NullReferenceException`.

If you want ALL the orphaned (i.e. no project) documents AND the documents that have projects that aren't deleted (i.e. you only exclude documents that belong to deleted projects) then:

```
.Where(m.Project == null || !m.Project.IsDeleted)
```

Comment: But this is not really what i want, here you saying, bring me the document where Project is not null and not deleted, what i want is, i want the documents that dont have projects, and i want the documents with project but not deleted ones.

Comment: @DarthVader: No I'm not. Read it again. It says "give me the documents that aren't deleted" AND that have EITHER NO PROJECT or have a project that is NOT deleted.

Answer (score 3):

```
.Where(arg => !arg.IsDeleted && (arg.Project == null || !arg.Project.IsDeleted))
```

With C# 6 the "Safe navigation operator" (`?.`) will get introduced, which brings following shortcut (similar to `??`):

```
.Where(arg => !arg.IsDeleted && !(arg.Project?.IsDeleted ?? false))
```

Anyway: I am not sure if this will work with every Linq-provider (like EF) as you've tagged your question with [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) generally.

Comment: `Safe navigation operator`, that's a new one on me.

Comment: But this is not really what i want, here you saying, bring me the document where Project is not null and not deleted, what i want is, i want the documents that dont have projects, and i want the documents with project but not deleted ones.

Comment: well if u see my model, project is nullable.

Comment: I've adapted my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that code does what the OP wants or even if any code exists that does... If the document is not associated to a project and you're querying projects, how do you intend to find these orphaned documents? You would have to query documents and check for the absence of a project... No query on projects could ever tell you which documents aren't included in the set.

Comment: EF or any other query providers aren't going to support the null propagation operator anytime in the foreseeable future.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal it looks to me as if `Document` is the root of the OP's query. Why do you believe that it's `Project` rooted?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair oh yeah I misread the code, that makes more sense now.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair There is no `Expression` representation for the null propagation operator, so it's actually impossible for any query providers to support it on the upcoming C#/.NET version.  Until that's added to .NET no query provider could support it even if they wanted to.